# Report Customization

Tags: relationships, reports

We have webform which we captured organization name, contact name and case assigned to manager(One of the contact type). We need to get all details in single report got contact and case details, but not able to get organisation name. can anyone help us how to select the organization name in custom php file, also we have created new template for this.

Comment: How is the organization name tied to the contact?  Is it an employer relationship?  Have you looked at the Extended Reports extension to see if it handles this?

Comment: are you looking for the field 'organisation' or 'current employer'?

Comment: Relationship created as individual(contact) to Organization

Comment: Also i need to get contact with another relationship [Advisor of/Enquired by] in the same report

Comment: i have selected civicrm_contact_sort_name with  one relationship, how to get the another contact name which is captured in webform

Comment: In the webform we have captured the 4 different types of contact with case and contact relationship build.. How to take these four in the same report

Comment: I would build a Drupal View